# convert number to million and billion format in java or jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there a way to convert a float value into million and billion format in java or jsp tags.

eg: value 145,835,504 should be represented as 145.8M

can this be done using any formatting tags in jstl...?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know about JSP, but in Java you can accomplish this with a couple of simple, easy to code, methods.

```
public String truncateNumber(float floatNumber) {
    long million = 1000000L;
    long billion = 1000000000L;
    long trillion = 1000000000000L;
    long number = Math.round(floatNumber);
    if ((number >= million) && (number < billion)) {
        float fraction = calculateFraction(number, million);
        return Float.toString(fraction) + "M";
    } else if ((number >= billion) && (number < trillion)) {
        float fraction = calculateFraction(number, billion);
        return Float.toString(fraction) + "B";
    }
    return Long.toString(number);
}

public float calculateFraction(long number, long divisor) {
    long truncate = (number * 10L + (divisor / 2L)) / divisor;
    float fraction = (float) truncate * 0.10F;
    return fraction;
}
```

Comment: you can put this java code inside an util and directly called it from JSP.